# Meaning of passage about clothes at a party from "The Longest Ride"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I found this in *The Longest Ride*

> And the Women? They wore boots and hats, too, but **between her (Sophia) sorority sisters and the rest of the women here, she noticed more short-shorts and bare midriffs than she'd ever seen in the campus quad on the first warm day of spring**. It might as well have been a Daisy Duke convention. **Marcia and the girls had gone shopping earlier that day, leaving Sophia feeling almost dowdy in her jeans and sleeveless blouse.**

Context -

Sophia is a student living in a hostel. She and her roommates and some other girls from their college had a night out and went to a party. Now in that quoted text the costumes of the people attended the party were being described.

Question -

1. What is the meaning of the first bold part of the quoted text?
2. And in the second bold part of the sentence does it describe Sophia's costumes which she wore in the party at night or is it talking about Sophia's costume earlier in the day?
3. And what is the meaning of "Daisy Duke convention"?

Comment: Umm... If you've ever watched *The Dukes of Hazzard*, you would understand it instantly. (I'm a little shy to post the picture here.) See the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_Duke. Daisy Duke usually wears her short-shorts. In your story, Sophia must have felt being out of fashion because her dress doesn't show enough of her skin comparing to other girls, not in the slightest.

Comment: For the meaning and similar use of "between" , see also [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/what-does-between-drink-and-dignity-mean?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

between her (Sophia) sorority sisters and the rest of the women here, she noticed more short-shorts and bare midriffs than she'd ever seen in the campus quad on the first warm day of spring

-- She is just saying the girls are all wearing very little clothing.  Their shorts are cut very high, and their shirts leave their stomachs exposed (bare midriff)

Marcia and the girls had gone shopping earlier that day, leaving Sophia feeling almost dowdy in her jeans and sleeveless blouse.

-- She is comparing what she is wearing now (at the party) to the outfits of her friends.  She feels her outfit is very modest.  The other girls bought new bolder outfits early to wear to this party, and she did not.

-- Daisy Dukes are blue-jeen shorts cut off very high, so most of you butt hangs out.  They are named after Daisy Duke from the TV show The Dukes of Hazard.

Comment: I am still in confusion about "between her sorority sisters and the rest of the women". Please give more explanation about it. And as for the second answer now I understand that Sophia's dress at the night party is being described. But doesn't the sentence as it was quoted sounds a bit strange, as it gives more impression that Sophia was wearing those cloths in the morning when her friends went for shopping leaving her behind.

Comment: Between her sorority sisters and the rest of the women  --  basically she's saying "by looking at both my sorority sisters and the rest of the women" or "when comparing myself both my sorority sisters and the other women"

As for the other sentence, I don't think it is strange.  I think she is explaining why her sorority sisters have the clothes and she does not.  Without knowing anything else about the story, and just reading this excerpt, I would conclude that earlier in the day her sorority sisters might have dressed more like her, but then they went shopping, and now look quite different

Comment: Still not bringing myself to that meaning. Any dictionary entry? And as for the other answer can you please explain more from grammar point of view?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Between?s=t. This lists "among" as a synonym.  Does it help to read it like that.  "Among her sorority sisters and the rest of the women here, she noticed..."

Comment: I think the closest I can come is http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Leaving?s=t where it describes leaving as to "leave out, or omit".  Because she was left out of the shopping, or omitted from shopping with them, she did not get new clothes, and as a result feels dowdy.